# Watchdog handler

Tags: linux

I’m interested in monitoring the processes running in a Linux system and determining when they are stuck/running endlessly  very quickly.
Once I determine this, I also want to take on some actions (like dumping some debug info, restarting the process, etc..).

I know I can detect stuck processes using systemd, but unfortunately I wasn’t able to take action (where can I specify a script that I want to run when some process heartbeats are missed ?)

Are you aware about other tools that act like watchdog monitors ?
(processes can register to them, start sending heartbeats, and in case some heartbeats are missed, the tools takes some actions.

I am aware I can write my own tool – I just want to know if there’s anything else offering this functionality.

Thank you,
Andreea

Comment: `top` should let you send any signal you want to a given process once you know what process you're after. If you're saying that you want something that will automate looking into this for you, then looking into nagios or zabbix is probably a good route.

Comment: Possible cross-post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/575396/linux-watchdog-handler

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for something with a lot more `problem->action` type of monitoring, which goes outside most built-in linux monitoring tools like:

- top
- vmstat
- lsof
- tcpdump
- netstat
- htop
- iotop
- iostat

I would recommend looking into something like `http://www.zabbix.com/` or `http://www.nagios.org/` for system monitoring. I currently use zabbix to monitor over 300+ unique hosts on multiple networks for my company. It is great for creating custom monitoring parameters with the added bonus of graphing historical data for easy visual monitoring and problem solving. You can also create `actions` to problems that my arise such as: `if cpu>80% -> email me@email.com "There is a problem!"` (that isn't actual syntax just an idea).